# NestedScrollView не скролится

Tags: java, android, nested-scrollview

Есть NestedScrollView, в котором находятся элементы. Но, контент не прокручивается. Прокручиваются элементы по горизонтали, которые находятся в RecyclerView, но не прокручивается вертикально сам NestedScrollView. В чём может быть проблема?

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nest"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView27"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
                android:text="Избранное"
                android:textColor="#3D3E52"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/likerec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
                android:text="Корзина"
                android:textColor="#3D3E52"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/likerec2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Какой контент не прокручивается? В вопросе вообще не отражена суть. Добавьте полную разметку, скриншоты и тд и тп. И вообще почитайте [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AndreyMihalev дополнил вопрос